# install datepicker only from ng-bootstrap

Tags: angular, npm-install, ng-bootstrap

I want to use datepicker from ng-bootstrap package: 
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview

Is there any way to install only the datepicker and its dependencies instead of all the package?

Answer (score 8):

You can't install only the datepicker, but you can import only the datepicker in your project.

The `ng-boostrap` [exports all the sub modules](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/bdfa99eb3a892a9bd9982625a3b037589d855ddf/src/index.ts), if you want to use only the datepicker you can import only the datepicker :

```
...
import { NgbDatepickerModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
...
@NgModule({
  imports: [..., NgbDatepickerModule.forRoot()],
  ...
```

When you will build your project, only this module from ng-bootstrap will be added to your bundle.

Comment: Thanks. I have asked because on our company we have special compiler that was built especially for our needs. the problem is that it is loading all the  @ng-bootstrap folder instead only the parts that I have imported.  currently i cann't change the compiler but my code only.

Comment: You can still create a custom library that only imports this module and export it. Then install your custom library in your project.

Comment: @ibenjelloun Then we have to add ng-bootstrap as a peer dependency. Don't we need to install that dependency again?